# Overlay Grid on top of Image inside ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I have the following markup:

```
<ScrollViewer>
   <StackPanel Orientation=Vertical>
      <Image />
      <Grid />
      <ItemsControl />
   </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Okay so the image is an animated *loading* gif.  When an event is completed the program displays the grid and the items control as well, and the user is able to scroll up and down.

In order to do this currently I just set the image to `Visiblity='Collapsed'` and the `Grid` and the `ItemsControl` to `Visible`.  How can I layer them so that the image is always underneath, and the grid and the items control are on top - so that when I fade out the grid and the items control the image appears underneath?

I know that there is an option for Z-Index, I tried placing the Image, Grid and ItemsControl inside a canvas and setting the Panel.ZIndex property but it didnt seem to work - for one when I set the opacity on the Grid to .5 I couldn't see the image underneath, and also the Grid didn't fill the space either (I need it to stretch to the size of the form).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <Image/>
        <StackPanel>
            <Grid/>
            <ItemsControl/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```